# How can i reduce the loading time of my domain?

Tags: server, loading

When i use chrome inspector, i can see that :

Screenshot 1 :
[Google inspector view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNjYv.jpg)

Screenshot 2 :
[Details view][2]

I don't understand why the loading time is so high.

You can see it here : [www.immobilier-neuf.com](http://www.immobilier-lmnp.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I do not know Google Inspector View, but a great tool for finding speed issues on your page is [Google Page Speed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?hl=de&url=www.immobilier-neuf.com). I have linked your domin already in the link.

In detail as Google Page Speed says, you should use the browser caching option. You can achieve this by the .htaccess file, if you run a standard apache webserver. Put the .htaccess file in the root directory of your page and insert the content below. Please edit the content to your needs.

```
# Caching
FileETag MTime Size

ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 weeks"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 weeks"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 weeks"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 months"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 months"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 months"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 months"
```

Next step, you should reduce the size of your scripts and minify them. Or load minified sources from a CDN.

I hope I gave you some input with which you go forward.

Best regards,

Martin